# .hasOwnProperty('getComputedStyle') false in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, hasownproperty

So I did a little work on a colour picker module adding the ability to parse human readable colours. I leveraged `.getComputedStyle()` to perform the conversion.

I implemented detection of the feature (should be IE 9+) with:

```js
window.hasOwnProperty('getComputedStyle')
```

This is when I noticed some strange behavior. In Chrome and FF this reported true as expected. However in IE 11 (which does support it) it reported false.

I'm a little stumped as to why this is happening. I've performed other ways of checking its support. I'm stumped however as to why IE reports false whilst it does support it.

Not too sure if this is overkill but this fiddle simply logs the response so you can see for yourself. https://jsfiddle.net/xrgrgrhe/

Comment: You can use `'getComputedStyle' in window`

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for the input, as i said iv'e already sorted actually performing the check for its support. I'm confused as to why `window.hasOwnProperty('getComputedStyle')` returns false even though IE11 does have it.

Comment: Might `getComputedStyle` be considered an inherited property by IE11? Then it would report `false`...

Comment: I guess it is inherited. `window.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('getComputedStyle')` returns true

Comment: I'm desperately trying to figure out why this matters.

Comment: @torazaburo because its interesting. It may not matter day to day but its still worth knowing. Same as hoisting. It happens but could be useful know why such things happen as apposed to just blindly accepting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't perform feature detection in this way; browsers aren't always consistent about where certain properties and methods are defined on the prototype chain. Instead, simply access the property:

```
if ( window.getComputedStyle ) {
    /* Proceed to use window.getComputedStyle */
}
```

Functions are *truthy*, while undefined is *falsy*. As a result, this test will pass if the method is defined *anywhere* on the prototype, rather than directly on the Window instance object.

For what it's worth, the original test in the question also returns *true* in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't answer the question. As i said i already successfully do feature detection. I implemented it as you suggest when i realised `.hasOwnProperty` couldn't be relied on for things like this. My question was about `.hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: I answered that, "...browsers aren't always consistent about where certain properties and methods are defined on the prototype chain."

Comment: sorry yes you did, i don't know how i managed to miss that first sentence. It's pretty obvious when you think about it. The Window object would be created as any other object and could have things inherited from other things. I assumed something like the window object would be created in a standard way that all browsers would follow. Think ill keep looking into it more quite interesting. Same as why browsers hoist. That quite interesting too.